# Is a barrel knot the same as a double/triple overhand knot?

Tags: knots

[Climbing.com](http://www.climbing.com/videos/triple-barrel-knot/)  has a video showing how to tie a **barrel knot** in the end of a rope. To me (and many of you, I suspect) this knot is the very commonly-used  **[double overhand knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/doubleoverhand/#ScrollPoint)**.

Confused, I looked for other uses of the term barrel knot and found this snippet on the Animated Knots page for a **[barrel hitch](http://www.animatedknots.com/barrel/#ScrollPoint)** (emphasis mine):

> "Barrel" Confusion: Unfortunately, the name Barrel has been applied to various other knots. Ashley himself used it as an alternative name (ABOK # 1413, p 259) for the Blood Knot. Some have applied it to the Poacher's Knot, e.g., descriptions by IRATA and Access Techniques, and others to the **Double Fisherman's**, e.g., Cave Now.

Also, [Wikipedia's list of knots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_knots) says a barrel knot's alternative name is the **[blood knot](http://www.animatedknots.com/bloodknot#ScrollPoint)**:

> Barrel knot (blood knot) - joins sections of monofilament nylon line while maintaining much of the line's inherent strength

However, the blood knot and double fishermans/double overhand are definitely different knots.

So what's happening here? Is this just another name for the same knot, or is this a clear misuse of the name by a well-established climbing website?

Answer (score 4):

The knot shown on Climbing.com is indeed a barrel knot, and yes the barrel knot they're showing you to tie is essentially a triple overhand, but the difference is *a barrel knot isn't defined by the number of overhand loops you put in it*. A barrel knot can have three, four, five, or more loops tied into it, a double overhand in the end of a rope can also be called a barrel knot.

The barrel knot doesn't have it's origins in climbing, it's a macrame knot *(technically called a 'barrel bead')* that has proven useful as a stopper in climbing rope. Catholic rosaries are tied using barrel knots, and it's used for finishing ends in macrame.

[image]

Comment: I don't mean to reference it authoritatively, but instead as a collaborative and common base of knowledge, hoping that at least one person would have thrown in some info. Is a barrel knot a generic term for a knot in which the rope forms a barrel? Some other references show the ends in different orientation, but look very similar from the outside.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, the knot in the video by climbing.com is not a double overhand knot. They do one additional turn, so I would call it a "triple overhand knot". Now if you google this term you get hits, but only videos/discussions, no entry in animatedknots.com or wikis. So I guess at climbing.com they just made up an in my opinion poor name instead of just calling it a variant of the double overhand knot.

The barrel hitch is not something commonly used in climbing. Therefore the use of barrel knot by climbing.com is not a misuse (it is not a trademarked anyway), just an arguably bad use.

The blood knot again is very different from all other here mentioned knots and used in fishing, so irrelevant too.